# xcodebuild doesn't see my new 'source trees' setting

Tags: xcode, preferences, xcodebuild

I have a change in my xcode preferences "Source Trees", but the command-line build tool 'xcodebuild' does not pick it up. It pick up the previous value. (The project inside xcode itself does build with the new value).

I think I need to delete an xcode preference file somewhere..... Does someone know where the preferences are stored? But perhaps something else is needed....
Who can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that deleting the file ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist did the trick.